# Can't Find SetupTools -

Tags: python, pip, plotly

I'm trying to install Plotly through pip, and I'm unable to install the Plotly packaging in particular. I get the following error:

```
C:\Python 3.6>python -m pip show SetupTools
Name: setuptools
Version: 39.0.1
Summary: Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
Home-page: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
Author: Python Packaging Authority
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: UNKNOWN
Location: c:\python 3.6\lib\site-packages
Requires:

C:\Python 3.6>python -m pip install Plotly
Collecting Plotly
  Using cached plotly-2.5.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\rskin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uw5jnlnh\Plotly\
```

I'm using Python 3.6 and both pip and setuptools are installed and up-to date. I'm able to install other Python packages with no issues. I think it may have soemthing to do with the location of my Python 3.6 file, but I'm not exactly sure Any ideas?

Comment: As a troubleshooting measure, can you try installing a different package? For example, try `python -m pip install extras`.

Comment: Probably because of a whitespace in the `Python 3.6` dir name.

Comment: First, try `python -c "import setuptools"`.

Comment: I've tried both of these, pip has successful installed a two different packages (both Numpy and extras) but is unable to install Plotly.

One this I've noticed is I have to change directories to have Python recognize pip, I have both my system and my user variables set to 'C:\Python 3.6'

Answer (score 0):

You might need pip and setuptools installed for your user:

```
pip3 install -U pip setuptools
```